# Awk evaluates one variable expression but not the same expression twice

Tags: html, regex, awk

I am trying to split a file into separate files and insert HTML navigation elements in each file. The script correctly splits the larger file on "Volume" and correctly evaluates n - 1 to construct the file name.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        f="\<html\> \<head\>Jury Transcript Volume 1\</head\>\<body\>\<h2 align=\"center\"\>Jury Transcript Volume 1\</h2\>"; 
        RS = "Volume"
    }
    {n++}
    {
        x="volume-01-page-" n - 1 ".html";
        print f>x;
    }
    {print > x}
    {
        y="\<span align\"left\"\>\<a href=\"jury-volume-01-page-\" n - 1 \.\"html\"\>Prev\</a\>\</span\>\<span align=\"right\"\>\<a href=\"jury-volume-01-page-\" n - 1 \.\"html\"\>Next\</a\>\</span\>";
        print y>x;
    }' jury-volume-01-base-prep-double.txt
```

Produces: jury-volume-01-page- as the links.

When I try not escaping the quotes on the HTML links, a syntax error is given for the period before the first "html" file extension for the navigation links.

The expression that creates the separate files (succeeds) and the expressions for the navigation links fails.

How do I create a successful calculation of the page before and page after the current page and insert that result into the navigation links?

There will be closing HTML code but I assume an answer for inserting the navigation links will suffice for that boilerplate as well.

Thanks!

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't escape the quotes that delimit the awk strings, only the quotes that you want to become part of the HTML. And the dot should be inside the strings. It's also not necessary to escape `>` and `<` characters that are inside the string.

```
y="<span align=\"left\"><a href=\"jury-volume-01-page-" n - 1 ".html\">Prev</a></span><span align=\"right\"><a href=\"jury-volume-01-page-" n - 1 ".html\">Next</a></span>";
```